# Naturally ordered semigroups unique up to isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having some trouble understanding the theorem stating that naturally ordered semigroups are unique up to isomorphism. I'm reading the version from Proofwiki:
http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Naturally_Ordered_Semigroup_Unique_up_to_Isomorphism

> Let $\left({S, \circ, \preceq}\right)$ and $\left({S\,', \circ',
> \preceq'}\right)$ be naturally ordered semigroups.
>
> Let:
>   $\bullet$ $0\,'$ be the smallest element of $S\,'$
>   $\bullet$ $1'$ be the smallest element of $S\,' \setminus \left\{{0\,'}\right\}
> = S\,'^*$.
>   Then the mapping $g: S \to S\,'$ defined as:   $$\forall a \in S: g \left({a}\right) = \circ'^a 1'$$ is an isomorphism from
>   $\left({S, \circ, \preceq}\right)$ to $\left({S\,', \circ',
>  \preceq'}\right)$.
>   This isomorphism is unique.
>   Thus, up to
>   isomorphism, there is only one naturally ordered semigroup.

I'm confused by the mapping definition, $\circ'^a1'$. I'm not sure what it's saying: the operator-superscript notation's not explained anwhere I can find, and it seems to be combining operators and elements from two separately defined semigroups. I'd have thought that $\circ'$ would be a mapping with its domain within $S\,'$, so you couldn't just feed in an element from $S$ unless you knew or assumed $S$ was a subset of $S\,'$. (I may well have the wrong end of a few sticks: I'm just a nosy layperson reading online maths texts out of curiosity, not a real student.)

Answer (score 0):

The map you refer to is defined in http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Recursive_Mapping_to_Semigroup/Powers_of_Commutative_Elements. You'll have to refer to http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Recursive_Mapping_with_Identity to make sense of the definition. As far as I can see the notation $\circ'^a1'$ is basically what would usually be denoted $1'^a$ if $a$ were a natural number, though this notation doesn't explicitly state the operator.